# Flip Image/ Animation so it follow the direction of movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello and thanks for reading this.

I have made a little movement script for my "Monster" in my game.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MonsterMovement : MonoBehaviour {
public Vector3 pointB;
bool facingLeft = true;

IEnumerator Start()
{
    var pointA = transform.position;
    while (true) 
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointA, pointB, 3.0f));
        yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointB, pointA, 3.0f));
    }
}

IEnumerator MoveObject(Transform thisTransform, Vector3 startPos, Vector3 endPos, float time)
{
    var i = 0.0f;
    var rate = 1.0f / time;
    while (i < 1.0f) 
    {
        i += Time.deltaTime * rate;
        thisTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, i);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

This script is simple, it moves the object / monster from a -> b and back again. and it keeps repeating it.

But how can I manage to flip the Image of the object so it follows direction of the movement.?

I really hope you can help me.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem.

I added this little code:

```
bool facingLeft = true;

void Flip(){
    facingLeft = !facingLeft;
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
```

And then change the while function:

```
while (true) 
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointA, pointB, 3.0f));
        if (!facingLeft) {
            Flip();
        }
        yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointB, pointA, 3.0f));
        if (facingLeft) {
            Flip();
        }
    }
```